# What I need to consider by createing gitignore file for mvc5

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, gitignore, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I want to use a gitignore file for my latest MVC-5 project but I don't know what I need to consider.

I found in the web this [site](https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudio):

I never used before github or other sites to store and share my project :)

Thanks for the answers

Comment: You can use the link one for basic in your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cameron Tinker said in their answer, the purpose of the `.gitignore` file is to let git know that you want to exclude files from source control - the most common reason to do so being that they are generated (based on the files you do check in).

The one you found, or [this one](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) (probably with the same contents) are good starting points if you work with Visual Studio - just download the file, and put it in the root of your repository with the name `.gitignore` (yes, that's a dot at the start). If you start seeing files in your repository which you want to exclude, just add a line to `.gitignore`.

If you're not working with Visual Studio, and only have `project.json` and some `.cs` files, you might as well start simple. In one of my projects, I have

```
PS> cat .gitignore
bin
obj
artifacts
.vscode
```

and that's it. If I stumble on more things I want to exclude, I add them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start at least with ignoring few categories of content:

1. Temporary files:

> *~*
>
> *.bak

2. Some very specific Visual Studio files like:

> *.dbmdl
>
> *.ncb
>
> *.suo
>
> *.vspscc

3. Folders:

> TestResults/
>
> bin/
>
> App_Data/
>
> obj/
>
> sql/
>
> debug/
>
> release/
>
> build/
>
> .nuget/
>
> .vs/

Answer (score 0):

In Git, .gitignore files are used to exclude tracking of specific files or groups of files. For example, you might not want to check in built DLLs of your code so you could add the wildcard `*.dll` to your .gitignore file to exclude them.